# Generics - call a method on every object in a List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to call a method on every object in a List - e.g.

Instead of

```
List<MyClass> items = setup();

foreach (MyClass item in items)
   item.SomeMethod();
```

You could do something like

```
foreach(items).SomeMethod();
```

Anything built in, extension methods, or am I just being too damn lazy?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, on `List<T>`, there is:

```
items.ForEach(item => item.SomeMethod())
```

The oddity is that this is only available on `List<T>`, not `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

To fix this, I like to add the following extension method:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it on ANYTHING that implements `IEnumerable<T>`... not just `List<T>`

Comment: How did I miss .ForEach ... sums up my day today! Nice extension method.

Answer (score 15):

```
items.ForEach(i => i.SomeMethod());
```

Comment: @Rosarch: Nope. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx note that coderush will suggest this as a change from foreach(var x in items) x.SomeMethod();

Comment: @Brian Genisio ya i think i noticed/fixed that at the same time as your comment...

Answer (score 4):

Lists have a [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0) method.  You could also create an IEnumerable extension method, [but it kind of goes against the spirit of Linq](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

Comment: Of course, as one of the commenters on that post demonstrated, sometimes there's no (tidy) substitute for ForEach. However, if it's just to call one or two methods on _every_ object in a container, using classic foreach really is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change a property on MyClass using MyMethod, use the 'Pipe' method from Jon Skeet's [morelinq library](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123211509/https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
items = items.Pipe<MyClass>(i => i.Text = i.UpdateText()).ToList()
```

The possibilities are endless! :)